# Android : Fragments Threads

Tags: android, multithreading

I am a newbie both in android and java multithreading space. 
Have this piece of code in my fragment but its not calling my method(refreshNewsFeed) in Run function could be something really silly that I am overlooking .. any help would really appreciate.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run(){    
    refreshNewsFeed();
}
});
t.start();
```

Thanks, Tam

Answer (score 0):

It could happen that your `Thread` object `t` gets deleted before the thead actually have chance to start and execute the code.

Try to move `Thread t` declaration from this method (it looks like you use local variable) to class members instead.

```
public class A extends B
{
  Thread _t;
  public void someMethod()
  {
    _t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run(){    
        refreshNewsFeed();
      }
    });
    _t.start();    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that its still the same after executing new Thread(new Runnable(){  line it doesn't want to go in.